# BuiltValue Serialization in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I am using JSON object in my flutter app. I am serializing the data using BuiltValue and json.decode(). The problem is the JSON is nested, and am facing issues resolving the proper value to use built value in a nested json. I have tried reading documentation but I couldn't find a heavily nested example. Here is my json and my class, I am also providing a test case with output for further understanding.

```
    import 'package:built_value/built_value.dart';
    import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
    import 'package:built_collection/built_collection.dart';

    part 'widget_model.g.dart';

    abstract class WidgetModel implements Built<WidgetModel, WidgetModelBuilder>{

      ObjectList get formObject;

      WidgetModel._();
      static Serializer<WidgetModel> get serializer => _$widgetModelSerializer;
      factory WidgetModel([updates(WidgetModelBuilder b)]) = _$WidgetModel;

    }

    abstract class ObjectList implements Built<ObjectList, ObjectListBuilder>{

      ElementList get listOfElements;

      ObjectList._();
      static Serializer<ObjectList> get serializer => _$objectListSerializer;
      factory ObjectList([updates(ObjectListBuilder b)]) = _$ObjectList;
    }

    abstract class ElementList implements Built<ElementList, ElementListBuilder>{

      BuiltList<FormObject> get elements;

      ElementList._();
      static Serializer<ElementList> get serializer => _$elementListSerializer;
      factory ElementList([updates(ElementListBuilder b)]) = _$ElementList;


    }

    abstract class ReferenceData implements Built<ReferenceData, ReferenceDataBuilder>{

      String get value;
      String get key;

      ReferenceData._();
      static Serializer<ReferenceData> get serializer => _$referenceDataSerializer;
      factory ReferenceData([updates(ReferenceDataBuilder b)]) = _$ReferenceData;


    }

    abstract class FormObject implements Built<FormObject, FormObjectBuilder> {


      @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'textAlign')
      String get textAlign;

      @BuiltValueField(wireName:'references')
       BuiltList<ReferenceData> get references;

      FormObject._();
      static Serializer<FormObject> get serializer => _$formObjectSerializer;
      factory FormObject([updates(FormObjectBuilder b)]) = _$FormObject;
    }
```

My Serializer file:

```
import 'package:built_collection/built_collection.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
import 'package:built_value/standard_json_plugin.dart';
import 'package:stepper/src/model/widget_model.dart';


part 'serializers.g.dart';

@SerializersFor([WidgetModel])
final Serializers serializers =
(_$serializers.toBuilder()..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())).build();
```

Here is my test case:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:stepper/src/model/serializers.dart';
import 'package:stepper/src/model/widget_model.dart';
import 'package:test/test.dart';

main() {
  String formObjectString = """{
      "FORMOBJECT": {
      "elements" : [{
        "textAlign": "left",
        "references": [{
                "value": "2018",
                "key": "year"
            }]
      }]
     }
   }""";


  group('test form object', (){
    test('test', () {
      ObjectList formObject = serializers.deserializeWith(ObjectList.serializer, json.decode(formObjectString));
      print(formObject);
    });
  });
}
```

Here is the output (printed formObject):

```
ObjectList {
  listOfElements=ElementList {
    elements=[],
  },
}
```

The problem is that element list is empty. This is strange because I am sure my elements are serialized.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: How do you deserialize? Can you add some example JSON content to your question that demonstrates how the JSON looks like that you try to deserialize? Do you get any error output?

Comment: Thanks for the help @GünterZöchbauer, I figured it out. I had not properly wired the json object. Thus I was not able to properly map the deserialized elements. I missed these statements @BuiltValueField(wireName: 'object'). Thanks for pointing out to look at the Json. That solves it.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
@SerializersFor([WidgetModel])
```

should be

```
@SerializersFor([WidgetModel, ObjectList, ElementList, ReferenceData, FormObject])
```

Comment: Do you remember all the parameters for all the classes?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? I just look it up when I need it. I mostly only remember if I used something myself already and then I can check how I did it in my own code.

Comment: I have been following you for more than a month here on SO and Github, you seem to be the only person who is most responsive in case of questions/issues for Dart/Flutter. So, for curiosity, I wanted to ask how do you remember everything?

Comment: LOL. I try to get involved somehow (answering SO questions, trying to make stuff work locally, ...). That's what helps me remembering. I'm working with Dart fulltime since 2013, so many things aren't that new to me as they might be to others. Also often I just remember where I have seen a discussion about a topic (Google Groups, GitHub, StackOverflow, ...) this allows to find discussions quicker. Mostly I'm just good with search, my memory is quite holey ;-)

Comment: As I am using composition in my abstract class, my WidgetModel already owns the other classes, thus I do not need to add each and every one separately for the Serializers. Only having a Serializer for WidgetModel does the trick here.